# Add a UIView on device screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiview

I want to add a UIVIew or other UI on iPad screen. If i minimize my application, then the UI should not disappear. Means UI will show on device screen not on application window.

Hope I described it properly and if anyone have any idea about that. Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible, sorry

Comment: Is it not easier to disable the home button on your app then? Assuming it's for enterprise/kiosk mode.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: You can't do this.

You can do this only when you get access to the device OS directly. Currently you can't alter anything with the OS. (I'm talking about the non-jailbreak devices)

Comment: Thanks for you prompt feedback Midhun. But we have the object of UIScreen. Can we not find a way to show any UI on UIScreen?

Comment: @Jack_iPhone: No, you can't. `UIScreen` is for representing hardware screen. It gives you the information about current screen, width and height etc.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a requirement, you may want to look into developing apps for jail broken iOS devices. [iPhoneDevWiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Main_Page)